# How to decrypt Google Chrome Login Data file (Linux)

Tags: linux, google-chrome, encryption, passwords

My /home filesystem was corrupted due to a faulty SATA cable recently, and fsck sent a bunch of files to lost+found. After this, Google Chrome lost all remembered passwords. Fortunately, I had backed up the entirety of `~/.config/google-chrome/` to another computer only a few days before, so I just copied it back. But even then, the passwords did not come back.

After some research, I found that the passwords are stored in a sqlite file called `Login Data`. I found the file and opened it with sqlitebrowser, and sure enough the saved accounts are there, but the passwords are encrypted.

From what I've researched. it's supposed to be fairly easy to decrypt them, but all the methods I've found are either for Windows, or they rely on an `os_crypt.encrypted_key` value being in the `Local State` file. Except, no such entry exists in that file.

After more research, I found Chrome might rely on KWallet (I use KDE Plasma) to encrypt & decrypt the passwords now. I don't know if KWallet was affected by the corruption (only 40 files are in lost+found). When I open KDE Wallet Manager, it says kdewallet `is currently closed`, and when I click on Open..., nothing happens.

Does anyone know how I can decrypt the passwords in the Login Data file?

My Chrome version is 91.0.4472.114

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to find a solution, I created a new wallet in KWallet and set that as the default - that didn't solve the problem initially. Then I tried to save a password in Chrome, and when I checked the passwords in settings, all my old passwords reappeared.

Comment: Be sure you backup your passwords!